# Simple Read Write Lock

Tags: c++, concurrency, locking, readwritelock

I find many read write Spin lock implementation over the internet are unnecessarily complex. I have written a simple read-write lock in c++.

Could anybody tell me , if I am missing anything?

```
int r = 0;
int w = 0;

read_lock(void) 
{
     atomic_inc(r); //increment value atomically
     while( w != 0);    
}

read_unlock(void)
{
   atomic_dec(r); // Decrement value atomically
}
write_lock(void)
{
 while( (r != 0) && 
            ( w != 0))
  atomic_inc(w); //increment value atomically
}

write_unlock(void)
{
    atomic_dec(w); //Decrement value atomically
}
```

The usage would be as below.

```
read_lock()
// Critical Section
read_unlock();

write_lock()
// Critical Section
write_unlock();
```

Edit:

Thanks for the answers. 
I now changed answer to that of atomic equivalent

Comment: It's not valid C++, and it seems to assume that things like `w++` are atomic.

Comment: You have no synchronization for your counters. This is *not* thread safe.

Comment: Go work through https://deadlockempire.github.io/#menu

Comment: Thanks for the link . I will go through the link

Comment: It's currently not valid C++ (has no return type on functions). But worse it is not idiomatic C++. These are C-functions calls that **MUST** happen in pairs to work. There is a pattern for that. Also this code is not exception safe. In addition to the questionable and undefined `atomic_*()` functions there looks like a bug in `write_lock()`

Answer (score 3):

If threads access `r` and `w` concurrently, they have a data-race. If a C++ program has a data-race, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

`int` is not guaranteed by the C++ standard to be atomic. Even if we assume a system where accessing an `int` is atomic,  `operator++` would probably not be an atomic operation even on such systems. As such, simultaneous increments could "disappear".

Furthermore after the loop in `write_lock`, another thread could also end their loop before `w` is incremented, thereby allowing multiple simultaneous writers - which I assume this lock is supposed to prevent.

---

Lastly, this appears to be an attempt at implementing a spinlock. Spinlocks have advantages and disadvantages. Their disadvantage is that they consume all CPU cycles of their thread while blocking. This is highly inefficient use of resources, and bad for battery time, and bad for other processes that could have used those cycles. But it can be optimal if the wait time is short.

Comment: Thanks eerorika for the answers. You are right, this is the implementation for spin lock. I have edited the post.  Spinlocks can be useful in operating systems , like in interrupt context , where one can't sleep.

Comment: If we use a system where all word manipulation are atomic , then  r++, w++ can be atomic right ?

Comment: @sysinit x86 has atomic increment instructions, so an increment can be atomic. But it also has non-atomic increment, which is more efficient. There is no reason why the compiler would choose to use an atomic operation with an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implemention would be to use a single integral value. -1 shows a current write status, 0 means it is not being read or written to and a positive value indicates it is being read by that many threads.

Use atomic_int and compare_exchange_weak (or strong but weak should suffice)

```
std::atomic_int l=0;

void write_lock() {
    int v = 0;
    while( !l.compare_exchange_weak( v, -1 ) ) 
       v = 0; // it will set it to what it currently held
}

void write_unlock() {
    l = 0; // no need to compare_exchange
}

void read_lock() {
    int v = l.load();
    while( v < 0 || !l.compare_exchange_weak(v, v+1) )
       v = l.load();
}

void read_unlock() {
    --l; // no need to do anything else
}
```

I think that should work, and have RAII objects, i.e. create an automatic object that locks on construction and unlocks on destruction for each type.

that could be done like this:

```
class AtomicWriteSpinScopedLock
{
   private:
      atomic_int& l_;

   public:
      // handle copy/assign/move issues

      explicit AtomicWriteSpinScopedLock( atomic_int& l ) :
         l_(l)
       {
           int v = 0;   
           while( !l.compare_exchange_weak( v, -1 ) ) 
             v = 0; // it will set it to what it currently held
      }

      ~AtomicWriteSpinScopedLock()
       {
           l_ = 0;
       }
 };
       
class AtomicReadSpinScopedLock
{
   private:
      atomic_int& l_;

   public:
      // handle copy/assign/move issues

      explicit AtomicReadSpinScopedLock( atomic_int& l ) :
         l_(l)
       {
          int v = l.load();
          while( v < 0 || !l.compare_exchange_weak(v, v+1) )
               v = l.load();          }
       }

      ~AtomicReadSpinScopedLock()
       {
           --l_;
       }
 };
```

On locking to write the value must be 0 and you must swap it to -1, so just keep trying to do that.

On locking to read the value must be non-negative and then you attempt to increase it, so there may be retries against other readers, not in acquiring the lock but in setting its count.

compare_exchange_weak sets to the first parameter what it actually held if the exchange failed, and the second parameter is what you are trying to change it to. It returns true if it swapped and false if it did not.

How efficient? It's a spin-lock. It will use CPU cycles whilst waiting, so it had better be available very soon: the update or the reading of the data should be swift.